# Contact name Tokens for multiple relationships

Tags: relationships, tokens

I have a contact (individual) owner of several organization. He will pay the membership for all organizations. I need to send a contribution receipt showing that

> John Doe
>
> paid 100€
>
> for
>
> Super cool organization 1
>
> Top organization 2

I've installed the [Related tokens extension](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.reltoken) but as written and read afterwards it needs an improvement for multiple relationships

> Provide more control or better defaults for what happens when a contact has more than one relationship of a given type. For example, many contacts may have more than one "Parent/Child", and the Related (Child)::First Name token obviously falls short here; at present it will use the relationship with the highest internal ID (typically the one most recently created), but it could be more desirable in various situations to use the one with the newest start date, or to concatenate them all into a comma-separated string, or any number of other things.

So my question is: how to find these fusion fields? Is it possible without coding?

Any clues?

Comment: should I create hidden custom fields that grab the organization names from the webform?

Comment: Help needed. I can't find any solution :-(

Comment: You can try the data processor extension and the data processor token output extension. With that you can create custom tokens from the UI. You first have to setup the data processor to retrieve the right data and then you can add a token output to the data processor. But not sure if it helps your particular case.

Comment: ok many thanks Jaap, I'll try immediately!

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP I've tried with one individual owning 2 enterprises but it returns only one entreprise. Do you think it is possible to get all B (child) contacts from A (Parent) contact with this extension?